# Update Issue in Jira via Email

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email, jira

I am creating an application in mvc that sends an email to JIRA to create an issue.  But I also want the issue to be update-able from my application which will then send an email to update the issue.  I know that you can add a comment to an issue using its key in the subject.

So can you add the key to the subject and have the body of the email in some format that will allow you're issue to be update (for example: the status of the issue or the description or summary of the issue)?

Are there any open-source plugins that will allow you to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jira only supports creating issues and adding comments by email as per [this page](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Creating+Issues+and+Comments+from+Email). [The Jira Enterprise Mail Handler](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.javahollic.jira.jemh-ui) plugin looks like it would handle your requirements but is not free or open source.

If you are using c#, why not use the [Jira API](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/API+Documentation)? It would give you much more control and should be more reliable than email.

There are some 3rd party libraries for c# for using the API, like this one: https://github.com/techtalk/JiraRestClient

Comment: I would like to use the JIRA API and yes it would work but one the JIRA was hosted offline so it would be awkward to send information to the system (and I was told to use email) I knew that plugin would help but was hoping for an open-source one, thanks anyway